# Why does Linux kernel uses get_random_int() to generate stack_canary or stack_top?

Tags: linux-kernel, random

There is a random number generator in Linux kernel. This usually is called LRNG(Linux Random Number Generator). We can use it by calling `get_random_bytes()`. 
But `stack_canary` and `stack_top` are generated by `get_random_int()`. 
Although Linux kernel has own good random number generator(LRNG), why does Linux kernel generates it by `get_random_int()`?
I think that it maybe is because of efficiency. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Just [read the source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=4.7#L1777):

> Get a random word for internal kernel use only. Similar to urandom but
>   with the goal of minimal entropy pool depletion. As a result, the random
>   value is not cryptographically secure but for several uses the cost of
>   depleting entropy is too high

That's why `get_random_int` doesn't just take the output of `get_random_bytes`. As it happens, the arguments here are wrong for two reasons:

- [Entropy doesn't actually deplete](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/). That's just a bogus calculation inside the kernel.
- Even if entropy did deplete, it would be no reason not to use a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator instead of an ad hoc construct. Just use a separate instance from the one that depletes the entropy for `/dev/random`. Performance could be a reason, but the difference between a proper CSPRNG such as Hash_DRBG/SHA-2 and the ad hoc construction here using MD5 is tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Linux's `/dev/random`, `/dev/urandom`, and `get_random_bytes()` tied to the same internal entropy pool. It is quite possible to drain it when using for just RNG and cause `/dev/random` to block and `/dev/urandom` to produce low-entropy output. This low entropy condition creates issues for crypto.